# how to bulk import 301 redirects in IIS 7 from csv or excel

Tags: excel, redirect, iis-7, import, bulk

is there a way to import/update 100's of 301 redirects in IIS 7 from excel or csv file

Excel file format currently consist of  two column 1st column consists of old urls and the 2nd column consists of new url kinda like this format

https://support.3dcart.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/297/12/how-do-i-import-my-301-redirects

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Copy the redirects in XML format from the web.config file, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="services.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/services" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="products.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/products" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Paste that in a new notepad document. Save that as web.xml. Open it in Excel. Excel should automatically make a schema and it should come out in a similar format to what you want. Format it further if you need. Save it as a CSV.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I may not have been clear in my question. I have a excel file consist of two columns. Column A consists of rows of old 301 redirects and column B has rows of new 301 redirect urls is there any easy way for me to change them like bulk import rather than click and change

Comment: http://iis7-rewrite.heroku.com/ might work for you. I've never tried it.

Comment: Luke thank you so much this looks very promising, I will try this on a test server and update you with the results

Comment: You were very close I will accept this anyways because you pointed me to the right path. I had to install ms urlrewriter 2.0 for IIS7/win2k8 and then it worked like a chram. Many thanks

Comment: The solution exports the redirects from iis to csv. It seems to me that the question is how to import from cvs to iis.